# Socket.io - how to use listeners

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've looked around for an answer regarding this question, I am not sure if I am going about this the right way.

I have a node.js application that uses socket.io to push and receive data from the node server to the client. Most of the requests sent to nodejs are through HTTP Requests while the data pushed to the website is received through a socket.

I currently have unique namespaces for each of the individual listeners (for example I have a feed with comments, this means I have ***feed/{ID}*** as the listener as well as each comment has ***comment/{COMMENTID}***. *This means if there are 25 feed posts, I would have 26 (including the feed) listeners listening for the feed alone.*

I am not entirely sure how socket.io pushes data through the listeners (is each listener a new socket?). In my mind, if I have a large amount of users online at one point and a single comments listener it will be hit many times with useless, unrelated data - in comparison to now where it will only receive data relevant to the user.

**What is the best way to set up the listeners?**

**Is more or less listeners beneficial?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bad way to use listener. You should use just

- socket.on('feed',feed)
- socket.on('comment',comment)

When you want to send data to feed listener, use "socket.emit('feed',{id:1})".
When you want to send data to comment listener, use "socket.emit('comment',{commentid:1})"

This will reduce you to just 2 listener.

Comment: What if, for example, I have 50,000 feeds for groups and 50,000 feeds for users? Then regardless of what page you are viewing you will get feed updates that are entirely irrelevant? Any reason as to why a single listener that will send to potentially 50,000 users instead of multiple listeners with 3,000 people is better?

Comment: That's your server's work to determine which user you should send socket.emit to or not. You shouldn't send socket.emit to all users. More listener mean more work to add for your server to check every nanosec/millisec (base on your server performance to run each event loop. It's node.js main concept.) You should check to send event only when there's an update to your feed/comment to only people who's involved with which would make a better performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, from my understanding socket.emit will emit to any connection that is connected to the socket regardless of what their listener is. Setting up a "Room Join" keeps an array of sockets connected on the server side and only emits to users that have registered with the room

Answer (score 4):

You should use Rooms to handle this. Each time a user is viewing a feed page, it register to a room and then you push only the relevant information to users based on the page they are actually seeing.

`socket.on('subscribe', function(data) { socket.join(data.room); });`
`socket.on('unsubscribe', function(data) { socket.leave(data.room); });`

then when you want to send information to a specific room

```
io.sockets.in('feed_1').emit('comment', data);
```

You can see the documentation here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did know about this, although it didn't come to mind when setting this up, I am probably going to refactor my code to use this now. But, what I am trying to understand is, will each listener you create open a new connection? Does this mean you should have only 1 or 2 listeners running? I have other separated listeners for features like "presence" & "message", etc.

Comment: Each client will have only one connection with the server. Socket.io will use the right listener based on the key you provide as the first parameter in `socket.on` or `socket.emit`

Comment: So does having a list of various listeners matter? What are the performance issues with having a bunch of different listeners vs a single listener?